# Php loop thourgh array of Request ids

Tags: php, html, mysql

```
    function LoadProtocols(){
    ?>
   <?php
    $result=mysql_query("SELECT id,name,Destination_port, Destination_port_range_start,   Destination_port_range_stop FROM protocols;");

    echo '<table class="tftable" border="1">';
    echo '<tr><th>protocol Name</th><th>Port</th><th></th></tr>';
    echo "<form method='POST' action=''>";

    if( $row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    mysql_data_seek($result,0);
    while( $row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
    echo "<tr>
    <td>".$row['name']."</td>
    <td> "?><input type="hidden" id="id" name="id[]" value=" <?php echo $row['id']?>"> <input id="txt_port" name="txt_port[]" type="text" class="required" title="Port. This is a required field" value=" <?php echo $row['Destination_port'] ?> "></td> 
    <?php
    echo "<td><a  onclick='return show_confirm();'><input name='update' class='button' type='submit' value='Update'></a></td></tr>";

    if(ISSET($_POST["update"]) and $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST"){   

    $id=$_REQUEST['id'];
    $port=$_REQUEST['txt_port'];
    $menu=$_GET['Menu'];
    $result=mysql_query("UPDATE protocols SET Destination_port=".$port." WHERE id=".$id.";");

    header("Location: Overview.php?Menu=".$menu."&Overview=1");
    }
    echo "</form>";
    }
    echo '<table>';
     }
```

I made a simple table which as got 3 columns, the first column is a name, second one has a textbox which contains a number (with a hidden id that I need) and last one is a button to update that specific row.

The big problem I have that it only updates the last row, therefore I read that you needed to add [] to ur names and loop through it to update that specific row.

It's still not working and I can't figure out how to just let one specific row update with that [] array.

Thank you for reading and helping.

Comment: please mention form tag.wheteher using per row or all rows under one form tag

Comment: A suggestion is to write clean code by separating HTML & PHP.

Comment: You should define keys to the id, tags, and name array in html. like name="id[<?=$row['id']?>]"

Comment: In general i think, that you have totally wrong approach on the problem. You should seperate your logic from your UI and not mysql mysql_* functions. You should consider using PDO and prepared statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$_request['id'] is nothing but array ,also header should not be in loop
so Write This

```
mysql_data_seek($result,0);
     $counter=0;
        while( $row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
        {
        echo "<tr>
        <td>".$row['name']."</td>
        <td> "?><input type="hidden" id="id" name="id[]" value=" <?php echo $row['id']?>"> <input id="txt_port" name="txt_port[]" type="text" class="required" title="Port. This is a required field" value=" <?php echo $row['Destination_port'] ?> "></td> 
        <?php
        echo "<td><a  onclick='return show_confirm();'><input name='update' class='button' type='submit' value='Update'></a></td></tr>";

        if(ISSET($_POST["update"]) and $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST"){   
        $id=$_REQUEST['id'];
        $port=$_REQUEST['txt_port'];
        $menu=$_GET['Menu'];
        $result=mysql_query("UPDATE protocols SET Destination_port=".$port." WHERE id=".$id[$counter].";");
    $counter++;
       // header("Location: Overview.php?Menu=".$menu."&Overview=1");
        }
```

Instead of this

```
mysql_data_seek($result,0);
while( $row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
echo "<tr>
<td>".$row['name']."</td>
<td> "?><input type="hidden" id="id" name="id[]" value=" <?php echo $row['id']?>"> <input id="txt_port" name="txt_port[]" type="text" class="required" title="Port. This is a required field" value=" <?php echo $row['Destination_port'] ?> "></td> 
<?php
echo "<td><a  onclick='return show_confirm();'><input name='update' class='button' type='submit' value='Update'></a></td></tr>";

if(ISSET($_POST["update"]) and $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST")
{   

$id=$_REQUEST['id'];
$port=$_REQUEST['txt_port'];
$menu=$_GET['Menu'];
$result=mysql_query("UPDATE protocols SET Destination_port=".$port." WHERE id=".$id.";");

header("Location: Overview.php?Menu=".$menu."&Overview=1");
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for helping but there is still one little  problem: ex. The statement says now Where ID="1[2]" because it's a request and takes the data out of the textbox. but 1[2] != 1 so it doesn't update

Comment: Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\Project Script\Overview.php on line 286 => Line of the sql query. Tried some things but still no luck

Comment: ECHO value of $_REQUEST['id'] ,you will get idea about what is happening